# Why could mount.cifs mount an empty folder?

Tags: linux, mount, samba, cifs

**gentoo, kernel 3.7.10

samba 3.6.12

SMB/CIFS server: Windows Server 2003 3790 Service Pack 2**

I've encountered the situation when `mount.cifs` behaves differently from `smbclient` program.

The following command works fine. I can log in the server and navigate through the share's contents.

```
smbclient -U domainname/username //server.name/sharename
```

And if I try to mount this very share folder with the following command,

```
mount -t cifs //server.name/sharename /mount/point -o user=domainname/username
```

then the command itself works fine (return code is 0, no error message). But `/mount/point` looks empty.

What's the problem? Why `mound.cifs` and `smbclient` behave differently? Maybe `smbclient` uses some hidden settings?

BTW, I don't know whether it is relevant to the problem but anyway. If I run `mount.cifs` command several times, I don't get any `folder already mounted` kind of message. Though afterwards I can run `umount` the same number of times until I get error `umount: /mount/point/: not mounted`

Comment: Is the share shown in the output of `mount` or in `/proc/mounts`? What are the permissions for the `domainname/username` on the server? By the way, `-o username=...` is preferred to `-o user=...`

Comment: Well, yes it is: `//server.name/sharename on /mount/point type cifs (rw)`

Comment: What about the rights the user mounting the share has on the server (for the share)?

Comment: @peterph Well... Does it really matter? I mean I use the same `username` in both cases and in the case I run `smbclient` I can read the contents of the share (i.e. at least I have read rights) and in the other, under the same username, I can't.

Comment: Oh, forgot about that. I would check it nevertheless. Do you happen to have a Windows installation you could use to check it behaves the same on Windows?

Comment: @peterph This is very strange: I have a Windows host and yesterday I could open the share in Explorer (\\server.name\sharename) and navigate there. Today I can't! Lools like 'Permission denied'. But I _can_ mount it as a network drive though. And it shows me empty folder as well. BUT! I stil can navigate there with `smbclient` from my linux host even today! :-)

Comment: At least it seems consistent. Can you actually fetch any data with `smbclient`, or do you just see a directory listing?

Comment: @peterph Yes, I can. And today I can open the share in my Windows Explorer. Alghough if I mount it as a network drive it is still empty (like on my linux host). Also today I've managed to mount another share on another server without any problem. So it is a peculiarity of the server. But which?

Comment: I guess access rights on the share for your user - might be just a mistake like: "disallow listing directory". If you know of a file that is there, you might try to open it directly by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem. Thanks to Wireshark.

From the Wireshark's logs I saw that when `smbclient` did its job then the peers exchanged GET_DFS_REFERRAL subcommands. But these messages were absent when I tried to mount the share with `mount.cifs`.

It seems the server uses Distributed File System facilities so I tried to add the support of DFS to the kernel and that made the trick. Now I can perfectly navigate, read and write in my mounted share.

Actually I thought that `smbclient` and `mount.cifs` used the same low-level instruments to connect to the SMB/CIFS servers but it isn't so. It looks like Samba can handle DFS itself without support of the kernel.

Comment: It's not clear how you added support to `DFS`.

Answer (score 1):

smbclient is not mounting the share, "mount -t cifs ..." instead is doing this. You need to be superuser to mount shares. Could you please try `sudo mount -t cifs //server.name/sharename /mount/point -o username=youruser,domain=yourdomain`?

Comment: If he didn't have root permissions the `mount` command would throw an error.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten to say that I did it as root.

Comment: Could you please try the command (as stated above)? Differences to your command: "username" instead of "user", domain parameter separated.thanks

Comment: Well, I've tried, 'username' hasn't helped.